# Ansible - extract more that 1 line from a specific column

Tags: ansible, yaml

so I have the following :

```
name: "gitea - list gitea users"
debug:
  var: users_checklist.stdout_lines


TASK [gitea - list gitea users] 

ok: [giteahost] => {

"users_checklist.stdout_lines": [
    
"ID   Username   Email                 IsActive IsAdmin",
    
"4    Superadmin something@example.com true     true",
    
"5      git        else@git.com          true     false"
```

What I want exactly is to extract all Usernames from the second column and till now I only managed to extract the 2nd line from 2nd column using :

```
name: "gitea - list usernames column"
debug:
  msg: "{{ users_checklist.stdout_lines.1.split().1 }}" 

TASK [gitea - list usernames column] 

ok: [giteahost] => {
"msg": "Superadmin"
```

.1.split().1
where 1 is actually 2nd line, split column with split() and the remaining 1 pointing to the data after the () space delimiter with the following output:

```
TASK [gitea - list usernames column] 

ok: [giteahost] => {

"msg": "Superadmin"
```

I tried putting stdout_lines.[1,2], stdout_lines.[1..2], stdout_lines.[1-2], stdout_lines.*, or stdout_lines.{1,2}, stdout_lines.{1..2} or {1-2} but with no success, please help me out guys!

10X a lot and have a nice day!

Comment: please indent your scripts with 4 spaces, and put your inline code  between backticks (i.e. ` character). That makes it easier to read your question.

Comment: I hope it's ok now, sorry about that, I'm using this site for some years till now but it's the first time I post something, 10x a lot for your time!

Comment: Great job! Certainly looks a lot easier to read. :-) And welcome at stackoverflow.

Comment: 10x a lot !!!Glad to be here and I really appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following Jinja2 command.

```
"{{ ( sers_checklist.stdout_lines | map('split') | map(attribute=1) | list )[1:] }}"
```

1. first the single entries are splitted: `map('split')`
2. for each line the element at position 1 is extracted: `map(attribute=1)`
3. the heading is removed: `[1:]`

Complete example task:

```yaml
- name: Extract usernames
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ( stdout_lines | map('split') | map(attribute=1) | list )[1:] }}"
  vars:
    stdout_lines:
      - "ID Username Email IsActive IsAdmin"
      - "4 Superadmin something@example.com true true"
      - "5 git else@git.com true false"
```

Produces the following output (so a list with 2 entries):

```
TASK [Extract usernames] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Superadmin",
        "git"
    ]
}
```

Comment: 10x a lot and have a nice day and weekend!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like the below:

```
{{  users_checklist.stdout_lines | map('regex_search','^\\d+\\s+\\w+')|select()|map('regex_search', '\\w+$')|list }}
```

The first `map('regex_search')` would filter out the first two columns of each row. Then, `select()` would remove the unmatched rows(header) and the 2nd `map('regex_search')` would filter the last column of the first two columns meaning the 2nd column.

**Example**:

```
---
- name: Sample play
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ foo | map('regex_search','^\\d+\\s+\\w+')|select()|map('regex_search', '\\w+$')|list }}"
    vars:
      foo:
      - ID   Username   Email                 IsActive IsAdmin
      - 4    Superadmin something@example.com true     true
      - 5      git        else@git.com          true     false
      - 1122 foobar     dddd@gmail.com          false   true
```

The above `debug` would return the following results:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Superadmin",
        "git",
        "foobar"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks P, have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach for this would be to format the data using some other tool in your ansible play, maybe run a python script in order to extract what you need (in this case - the user names) to a list (use `register` in order to extract it) and then iterate over the user names using `with_items` keyword.

Comment: this is a little bit too much for me considering that I'm quite new in Ansible :(

Comment: I suggest taking it step by step: 1. Try and work out how can you parse this list in python to get a list of user names. 2. Check how can you run a script using ansible. 3. Check how to get a result of a task to an ansible variable. 4. Check how to loop through a list variable in ansible. These steps should result in you accessing all user names in your ansible play